# System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new RSACryptoServiceProvider()' before all references to it are out of scope

Tags: c#, moq

I'm currently using the `moq` framework to write some unit tests for my C# application. In one of my tests, I have the following code:

```
private ICryptoProvider GetMockCryptoProvider(bool rsaKey = true)
{
    var result = Mock.Of<ICryptoProvider>();

    Mock.Get(result)
        .Setup(mock => mock.GetRsaKey(rsaKey))
        .Returns(new RSACryptoServiceProvider());

    return result;
}
```

When I try building this, I get the following error:

> In method 'LoginServiceUnitTests.GetMockCryptoProvider(bool)', call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new RSACryptoServiceProvider()' before all references to it are out of scope.

Anyone familiar with `moq` know what might be causing this?

Comment: Builds fine for me. is this happening on build or when you run the test?

Comment: @Nkosi, it does build in VS, but not on our build system. So maybe something there.

Comment: Narrow down if it happens when test is being compiled or when it is run.

Answer (score 1):

On your build server you probably have MS Code Analysis enabled, and also treat warnings as errors. Message you provided is actually result of [CA2000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx) "Dispose objects before losing scope" code analysis rule, which is violated in `GetMockCryptoProvider`.

It's violated because you don't dispose `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. In this case you probably don't need to, assuming that `ICryptoProvider` itself implements `IDisposable` and just wraps `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. In such case you can just supress this warning, because as stated by the links above, section "When to supress this warning":

> or if the method that raised the warning returns an IDisposable object
>   wraps your object.

To supress it, decorate your method like that:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2000:DisposeObjectsBeforeLosingScope")]
private ICryptoProvider GetMockCryptoProvider(bool rsaKey = true)
```

Comment: One class simply inheriting from another that is IDisposable in no way makes it work or not needing to dispose it. If it's IDisposable it needs wrapping in a using statement or disposing manually once it's finished with

Comment: @angelsix OP returns instance of class that wraps RSACryptoServiceProvider (IDisposable in question) from function - he cannot dispose it, that will be a task of the caller.

Comment: Ah ok noted. So this is an issue with VS not being able to detect the chain upward that it is getting disposed?

Comment: Sometimes it's not even possible (say you pass wrapper class to third party code), but if you use wrapper in your own code and do not dispose - there will be another such warning, now for the method you don't dispose wrapper in. Anyway, documentation of this rule suggests to disable it in this specific case (disable for this method only of course, not globally).